# Which callback will be executed when vue-resource recieved status code 403?

Tags: http, vue.js, vue-resource

[vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) provides me two callbacks:

```js
{
  this.$http.get("/my-api").then(
    response => {
      // success callback
    },
    response => {
      // error callback
    }
  );
}
```

However, I still don't know which callback will be executed when vue-resource recieved status code `403`.

If I successfully hit the API, but API response me `403`, is that consider an error callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback will be executed is error callback.

> but API response me 403, is that consider an error callback?

Answer: Yes, the 403 status is considered error. Because you don't have permission to access the resource.